# Session array issue

Tags: php, arrays, session, loops, for-loop

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $prodid => $qty => $size ){
```

This line of code keeps bringing up the error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting  ')' 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShoeShop\cartPage.php on line 29
```

Does anyone know how to fix it ?
I have very little knowledge of arrays.

Comment: Are you sure you closed all brackets? It says that perhaps you are missing a `)` somewhere.

Comment: what is code on line no 29

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $prodid) {
    foreach($prodid as $qty => $size) {

    }
}
```

[`foreach` loops](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can either be in the format of `foreach(array() as $value) {}` or `foreach(array() as $key => $value) {}`, currently you have `foreach(array() as $key => $value => ???) {}`.  This would be assuming that `$_SESSION['cart']` is in the format of:

```
Array(
    Array(
        qty => size,
        qty => size,
        qty => size,
    ),
    Array(
        qty => size,
        qty => size,
        qty => size,
    ),
);
```

If your array looks more like this:

```
Array(
    Array(
        prodid,
        qty,
        size,
    ),
    Array(
        prodid,
        qty,
        size,
    ),
)
```

Then your loop will be even simpler:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
    $prodid = $item['prodid'];
    $qty = $item['qty'];
    $size = $item['size'];
}
```